# Separating input by tags

Tags: c++, substring, substr

I am trying to separate input from the user by "Tags" ex: `<b>` and `</b>`

**Code:**

```
string toAdd;    
int iSlide = 0;    //before the first tag
iSlide = input.find("<");
toAdd = input.substr(0, iSlide);
cout << toAdd << endl;    //the first tag                                   
//   cout << input[input.find(">")+1] << endl;                         
int iNext = input.find(">");    
cout << input[iNext +1];    
toAdd = input.substr(iSlide, iNext+1);    
cout << toAdd << endl;    
iSlide = input.find(">" + 1);
```

I'm working with the example `Hello my name is <b>1 Tori </b>2 wow!`
The commented out cout statement prints the correct closing tag, but when I use it to substring, it seems to be using the last closing tag. Any thoughts about what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `input.substr(iSlide, iNext+1)`, you appear to expect both of the parameters to be indexes into `input`.  Only the first parameter is an index.  The second parameter is a length.  As a result, you're getting too long of a string.  If you compute the length of the match then you should get the string you want.

Also a hint for the future, don't put multiple lines of instruction in one line of text.  It is hard to read, understand, and debug the way you wrote it.  You will be much happier to do one thing for each line of source code.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for helping me understand that and for the tips!